# Can someone help me why this circuit won't simulate on Tinkercad?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, bjt, dc-motor

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to create a H-bridge in Tinkercad but it doesn't want to simulate for some reason and I don't know why. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you driving the transistors? What measurement shows the circuit not working?

Comment: I'm not familiar with tinkercad. Can it normally simulate motors? I'm not aware of many SPICE models out there for motors.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is** not clear without ABCD voltage timing descriptions.

This H bridge has a common fault when either pair on left/right side are conducting calked "shoot-through" during transitions.

Therefore it is essential to use fast turn off times and slow rise times to create say a 1us deadtime during transitions. The deadtime will vary with different designs depending on L/R ratio and LdI/dt and self-resonant frequency and may be sub-microsecond for low BEMF.

If you can do the fast pullup slow turn on using different resistors in parallel, one with a lower value and a diode to turn off faster, you will succeed. keep in mind transistor input capacitance varies with power rating but can be in the low pF range for low power when computing RC rise/fall times.

Normally for logic level drive signals an extra NPN common emitter drive with a pullup R to PNP base for high side drive is essential,

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why the simulator is complaining, but the circuit won’t work with 5V Arduino Uno outputs driving the high side PNP transistors. You need to get up to the 9V input voltage to turn those transistors off.

The simulator should show it not working, but perhaps there is a problem with a missing model or something of that ilk.